# split a key in a dic and its values to multiple keys/values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following dic:

```
dic = {'shape': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'item1_item2_item3': ['1_2_3', '5_6_10', '3_7_9']}
```

I want to convert it to:

```
dic = {'shape': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'item1': ['1', '2', '3'], 'item2': ['5', '6', '10'], 'item3': ['3', '7', '9']}
```

Basically, I want to split based on '_' and make new keys/values out of the original key and its values.

The size of the second key might have more items; for example 'item1_item2,item3,item4'.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: I saved the file to csv and opened it again by reading line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip()` to pair up the split key and values; you'll want to build a new dictionary here:

```
new = {}
for key, value in dic.items():
    if '_' not in key:
        new[key] = value
        continue

    for new_key, new_value in zip(key.split('_'), value):
        new[new_key] = new_value.split('_')
```

You could mash this in to a dictionary comprehension but it becomes rather harder to follow:

```
{nk: (nv.split('_') if '_' in k else v)
 for k, v in dic.items() for nk, nv in zip(k.split('_'), v)}
```

Demo:

```
>>> dic = {'shape': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'item1_item2_item3': ['1_2_3', '5_6_10', '3_7_9']}
>>> new = {}
>>> for key, value in dic.items():
...     if '_' not in key:
...         new[key] = value
...         continue
...     for new_key, new_value in zip(key.split('_'), value):
...         new[new_key] = new_value.split('_')
... 
>>> new
{'item2': ['5', '6', '10'], 'item3': ['3', '7', '9'], 'shape': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'item1': ['1', '2', '3']}
>>> {nk: (nv.split('_') if '_' in k else v)
...  for k, v in dic.items() for nk, nv in zip(k.split('_'), v)}
{'item2': ['5', '6', '10'], 'item3': ['3', '7', '9'], 'shape': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'item1': ['1', '2', '3']}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wanna do it's this:

1. Extract the key that you wanna split
2. split it and assign it to a new list
3. assing the values of the key to a list of the new list and append it to the new key
4. delete the old key and value

To get you started

```
dic = {item: "whatever", item1_item2_item3: [1,2,3], [2,3,4]. [4,5,6]}
copy = dic[item1_item2_item3]
name = item1_item2_item3
name = name.split("_")
#this make a list like this: [item1, item2, item3]
for i in len(name):
    dic[name[i]] = copy[i]

del.dic[item1_item2_item3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split string using `my_string.split("_")` to get a list strings. Here's one solution to split the strings and the keys and assign the new values:

```
dic = {'shape': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'item1_item2_item3': ['1_2_3', '5_6_10', '3_7_9']}

new_dic = {}

for k in dic.keys():
    val = dic[k]
    subkeys = k.split("_")

    if len(subkeys) > 1:
        for s in range(len(subkeys)):
            subkey = subkeys[s]
            subvals = val[s].split("_")
            new_dic[subkey] = subvals

    # this handles the case where the key has no underscores
    else:
        new_dic[k] = val

print new_dic
```